# TextView 1 or 2 lines

Tags: android

I want my TextView to be either 1 or 2 lines if needed. I would expect this to work but it doesn't:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:maxLines="2"
    local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
```

If I change `android:minLines="1"` with `android:lines="2"`, then it takes 2 lines. But the problem with that is that the height will always be 2 lines even though the text can fit in 1 line (and thus pushing the view below it further than needed).

Comment: You need dynamic lines?

Comment: what happens if you take out min lines?

Comment: Using android:maxLines="2" is enough.You don't need minLines or lines to be defined.If it will take at max 2 line and if the text can be accommodated in 1 line,it will only take that 1 line

Comment: Yes, it needs to be dynamic because it's in a vertical `LinearLayout` and the view below it should not have any space in between

Comment: If I remove `android:minLines="1"` it stay as 1 line (when it should be 2 since the text is longer)